# Gnome keyring unnamed personal certificates issued by no one

Tags: certificates, gnome-keyring

Using Seahorse, under *Certificates > Default Trust*, I see that I have nine personal certificates called `(null)`, issued by "No Name", which give absolutely no information when I look at their properties.  So:

1. Where do they come from?
2. What (if any) purpose do they serve?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1267127/seahorse-shows-several-suspicious-null-personal-certificates?noredirect=1#comment2144846_1267127